# Web socket server inheritance chain in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to achieve a hierarchy of servers in my node.js platform. I like to keep things malleable and would love to keep my base server classes open enough to be TCP or UDP or web socket based (or anything else for that matter).

The ideal hierarchy would look like

`WebSocketChatServer extends ChatServer extends Server`

`WebSocketGameServer extends GameServer extends Server`

`WebSocketMatchmakingServer extends MatchmakingServer extends Server`

Meaning I could also do

`TcpChatServer extends ChatServer extends Server`

Now, why can't I do this?

**Server**

- manages generic `Client`s
- can route incoming commands
- does not listen on any port since it doesn't know if its UDP, TCP, websocket, etc

**ChatServer**

- manages generic `ChatClient`s
- creates default chat channels (eg "General Chat")

**WebSocketChatServer**

- listens to `ws` or `wss` on some port
- creates new clients and listens to web socket events
- spins up required http/https server
- sets ssl

So therein lies the problem. All my actual websocket handling is all the way at the top level. This means that `WebSocketGameServer` and `WebSocketWhateverServer` would need all methods copy-pasted into them. A more appropriate way would be

`ChatWebSocketServer extends WebSocketServer extends Server`

`GameWebSocketServer extends WebSocketServer extends Server`

`MatchmakingWebSocketServer extends WebSocketServer extends Server`

Now all three of those `WebSocketServer` types have all required websocket logic. BUT, now I've lost the genericness of `ChatServer`, `GameServer`, etc..

What can I do to keep `ChatServer`, `GameServer`, and any other `Server` generic and then implement them into `WebSocketServer`s without duplicating all the web socket listeners and handlers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an abstract interface for the communication layer, and have it be something the classes in the `Server` hierarchy *use* rather than something they *are* (aggregation/composition rather than inheritance). You could even make it something injected into the `Server` constructor (one form of dependency injection), which might be handy for testing.

You'd then implement the interface for TCP, for WebSockets, etc., keeping those purely to the details of mapping the concrete communication method to the abstract communication interface.